# How do I perform bullet/enemy rectangle collision detection in a Space Invaders-like game?

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, collision-detection

I have recently posted a question regarding firing bullets which I (with help of course) managed to figure out. I now have a new problem, I am unable to figure out collision detection between bullets and my enemies. I don't wan't to post all my code at once so here's the list of my classes the code in which I will post at your request:

- cButton (this is just a 'play' button no help required).
- bullets
- Game1
- enemies

P.S. this is only my second post, go easy on me ;)   **NOTE:** the player only moves side to side and the enemies move from top to bottom in a strait line (if that helps at all)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple way of doing it that I've used before. Set up a rectangle around the bullet:

```
Rectangle bulletRect = new Rectangle(bulletPosition.X, bulletPosition.Y, bulletText.Width, bulletText.Height);
```

The same for an enemy:

```
Rectangle enemyRect = new Rectangle(enemyPosition.X, enemyPosition.Y, enemyText.Width, enemyText.Height);
```

Then when testing collisions you can use:

```
if(bulletRect.Intersects(enemyRect))
{
   //We have a collision
}
```

Comment: sorry for the question, i'm new to programming, but do i put the Rectangle statement in the class bullets method? and if so where exactly do i need to put this if statement?

Comment: The if statement would go in the games update event, you want to check for collisions constantly after all. As for the rectangles you'll want a property to hold them, one for your bullets class and one for the enemy class. Or you could just have a BaseClass that holds a rectangle, among other commonly shared properties, and then let your enemy/player/bullet objects inherit from it e.g. `Player : GameObject`.

Comment: What do you mean by a "property to hold them" (sorry if this is a silly question lol).

Comment: public Rectangle bulletRectangle 
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return new Rectangle(position.X, position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);
                    }
                    set 
                    {

                    }

                }  is this the correct way of setting this property and if so what do i need to put in the 'set' statement?

Comment: You would have a private variable that you would use internally e.g. `Private Rectangle _enemyRect;` then you would have the property `Public Rectangle EnemyRectangle{get{ return _enemyRect; } set{ _enemyRect = value; }` That way each instance of your enemy object has it's own associated rectangle. How you populate the rectangle is up to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14289/discussion-between-jack-minney-and-duane)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you'll have to check if the bullet entered a block that a ship is currently occupying, and if so destroy it and remove the bullet. It would probably help if you posted the relevant code. :)

Comment: hey Shawn, i was following a tutorial on a forum and it told me to put this code into their respective classes:       public Rectangle bulletRectangle() 
                {  
                   return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, (int)texture.Width, (int)texture.Height);
                }  and then use a nested for loop (which i have deleted) but this didn't work, would you happen to know the tags for  indenting my code snippet?

Comment: I don't think you can in comments. :) That nested for loop might have been checking for a collision.

Comment: Yeh i think they mentioned that but on one of the lines i think it was something like:  if(bullet.bulletRectangle.Intersects(Enemy.enemyRectangle()))  i kept getting an error, cant remember what it said :(

Comment: Repeat what you did to get the error and you won't have to remember. :)